# Не работает переключение дат C#

Tags: c#, .net

В коде не работает переключение между датами. Оно описано в menu(). После того как в inf() появилось переключение по вертикали, переключение дат перестало работать. Как заставить ее работать?

```
namespace ezednevnik
{
    class Programm
    {
        static void inf(string data)
        {
            if (data == "13.10.2023")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     1.Сходить похавать");
                Console.WriteLine("     2.Сходить погулять");
            }
            if (data == "15.10.2023")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     1.Помыть террариум");
                Console.WriteLine("     2.Покормить улиток");
            }
            int position = 2;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key1 = Console.ReadKey();
            while (key1.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0,position);
                Console.WriteLine("  ");
                if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow & position>2)
                {
                    position--;
                }
                else if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    position++;
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, position);
                Console.WriteLine("->");

                key1 = Console.ReadKey();
            }
            if (position == 2 & data == "13.10.2023")
            {
                thirteenoctober_num1();
            }
            if (position == 3 & data == "13.10.2023")
            {
                thirteenoctober_num2();
            }
            if (position == 2 & data == "15.10.2023")
            {
                fifteenoctober_num1();
            }
            if (position == 3 & data == "15.10.2023")
            {
                fifteenoctober_num2();
            }
        }
        static int strelk(ConsoleKeyInfo a)
        {
            int p = 2;
            if (a.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                p++;
            }
            if (a.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                p--;
            }
            if (p == 1)
            {
                p = 2;
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, p);
            Console.WriteLine("->");
            return p;
        }
        static void menu()
        {
            string date_;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                date = date.AddDays(-1);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                date = date.AddDays(1);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Дата:");
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToLongDateString());
            date_ = date.ToShortDateString();
            inf(date_);
        }
        static void thirteenoctober_num1()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Дата - 13.10.23 - 1.Сходить похавать");
            Console.WriteLine("Описание: Сходить похавать, мб на кухню");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                menu();
            }
        }
        static void thirteenoctober_num2()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Дата - 13.10.23 - 2.Сходить погулять");
            Console.WriteLine("Описание: Сходить погулять, куда-нибудь");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                menu();
            }
        }
        static void fifteenoctober_num1()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Дата - 15.10.23 - 1.Помыть террариум");
            Console.WriteLine("Описание: Помыть улиточный террариум и постирать мат");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                menu();
            }
        }
        static void fifteenoctober_num2()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Дата - 15.10.23 - 2.Покормить улиток");
            Console.WriteLine("Описание: Сделать салатик и покормить им улиток");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                menu();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                menu();
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что должно это приложение делать? Вот вы написали  что не работает как надо, а как надо?

Answer (score 0):

Из `inf` нужно возвращаться по нажатию стрелок влево или вправо (и Esc добавил для завершения программы). Надеюсь, остальное сами доделаете.

Только изменённые методы, остальное пропущено (...). Изменения выделены "// ---".

```
class TestArithmeticOverflow {
    class Programm
    {
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        static ConsoleKeyInfo inf(string data)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            if (data == "13.10.2023")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     1.Сходить похавать");
                Console.WriteLine("     2.Сходить погулять");
            }
            if (data == "15.10.2023")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     1.Помыть террариум");
                Console.WriteLine("     2.Покормить улиток");
            }
            int position = 2;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key1 = Console.ReadKey();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // условие в след. строке - возврат, если стрелка влево/вправо или Esc
            if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow
                || key1.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow
                || key1.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) return key1;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            while (key1.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0,position);
                Console.WriteLine("  ");
                if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow & position>2)
                {
                    position--;
                }
                else if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                {
                    position++;
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, position);
                Console.WriteLine("->");

                key1 = Console.ReadKey();
            }
            if (position == 2 & data == "13.10.2023")
            {
                thirteenoctober_num1();
            }
            if (position == 3 & data == "13.10.2023")
            {
                thirteenoctober_num2();
            }
            if (position == 2 & data == "15.10.2023")
            {
                fifteenoctober_num1();
            }
            if (position == 3 & data == "15.10.2023")
            {
                fifteenoctober_num2();
            }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            return key1;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }

        ...

        static void menu()
        {
            string date_;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(); // первое нажатие,
            // потом код возвращается из inf
            do { // цикл теперь здесь
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                {
                    date = date.AddDays(-1);
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    date = date.AddDays(1);
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Дата:");
                Console.WriteLine(date.ToLongDateString());
                date_ = date.ToShortDateString();
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                key = inf(date_);  // код возвращается из inf
            } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); // завершение программы по Esc
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }

        ...

        static void Main(string[] args) {
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                menu(); // цикл перенёс в меню
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }
    }
}
```

Для дальнейшего улучшения кода нужно объединить `inf` и `menu`, и перенести это всё в `Main`. Меню и описание действий нужно поместить в какие-то массивы или списки. Для демонстрационных целей я сделал два меню: для чётного и нечётного дней. Меню хранится в списке и может иметь произвольное количество пунктов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Programm {
    static DateTime date;
    static int pos;
    // data[I][J][K]:
    //     I - номер меню, 0 для чётного дня и 1 для нечётного;
    //     J - номер пункта меню;
    //     K - 0 - название пункта, 1 - описание. 
    static List<string[]>[] data = new List<string[]>[] { new List<string[]> { new string[] { "Сходить похавать", "Сходить похавать, мб на кухню" }
            , new string[] {"Сходить погулять", "Сходить погулять, куда-нибудь" }
            , new string[] {"Лечь поспать", "Выспаться хорошенько" } }
        , new List<string[]> { new string[] { "Помыть террариум", "Помыть улиточный террариум и постирать мат" }
            , new string[] { "Покормить улиток", "Сделать салатик и покормить им улиток" } } };
    static void DisplayInfo() {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Дата - {0} {1}. {2}", date.ToLongDateString(), pos, data[date.Day % 2][pos - 2][0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Описание: {0}", data[date.Day % 2][pos - 2][1]);
        Console.ReadKey();
        GoToDate(0);
    }
    static void Reposition(int dt) {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, pos); Console.Write("  ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, pos += dt); Console.Write("->");
    }
    static int GoToDate(int dt) {
        date = date.AddDays(dt); int n = data[date.Day % 2].Count;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Дата: {0}", date.ToLongDateString()); Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("   {0}. {1}", i + 1, data[date.Day % 2][i][0]);
        pos = 2; Reposition(0);
        return n;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        date = DateTime.Now;
        int n = GoToDate(0);
        ConsoleKey key;
        while ((key = Console.ReadKey().Key) != ConsoleKey.Escape) {
            if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow) n = GoToDate(-1);
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow) n = GoToDate(1);
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && pos > 2) Reposition(-1); 
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && pos < 1 + n) Reposition(1);
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.Enter) DisplayInfo();
            else Reposition(0);
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2 + n);
    }
}
```